# Why is this Java 8 method reference not working for System.out.println(LocalDate::now);?

Tags: java, java-8

Maybe I am not fully understanding the concept of Java 8 functional interfaces and/or method references. I just don't understand why the following code has "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface":

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

interface Today{
    LocalDate getTodayDate(); 
}
```

Class to test:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Today today = () -> LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(today::getTodayDate);//Problem with this one                 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you think this would work?

Answer (score 3):

You're using your method reference in a context where its target type is unknown.

It would have worked if `java.io.PrintStream` had a method like the following:

```
public void println(Today dateSupplier){
    print(dateSupplier.getTodayDate());
}
```

But that's not the signature of `println`.

There's no reason to do this, but the way to make your code work is to invoke your own interface method, but this can't be justified...

```
System.out.println(today.getTodayDate()); //calls println(Object)
```

Unless this contract involves more than one classes/types, you may need to redesign your code.

Answer (score 3):

In your question description you say that the error you get is: "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"; but the line where you show that:

```
System.out.println(today::getTodayDate);//Problem with this one
```

would exhibit a different error message. So I guess a broader explanation is needed.

It seems you first need to create a `@FunctionInterface` called `Today`  for this code to work, something like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Today {
    LocalDate getTodayDate();
}
```

When that is created, this would work too:

```
Today today = () -> LocalDate.now();
```

which would be equivalent of:

```
Today today = LocalDate::now;
```

There's not a real need to create `Today` since `java.util.Supplier<T>` exists and does the same thing - takes nothing as input and returns `T`; but if you wanted to play around - you could.

Actually the fact that you have introduced this `Today` interface will make explaining things a bit easier.

The compiler sees : `today::getTodayDate` (in the `System.out.println(today::getTodayDate);` line) and has to "understand" what that is; it could be *at least* two things : `Today` *or* `java.util.Supplier` - it can't tell for sure; that is why it is said that lambda expressions and methods references are *poly expressions* - their type is inferred in the context of usage (just like generics). Since the compiler can't tell what that really is, it fails.

You could make an explicit cast to the type for this to compile:

```
System.out.println((Today) today::getTodayDate);
```

or:

```
System.out.println((Supplier<LocalDate>) today::getTodayDate);
```

But the problem is that even if this compiles and works and prints "something" - what it really prints is un-specified in the `JLS` and is implementation specific.

Comment: *When that is created, this would work too:...* If I am not mistaken, that would work with OP's code as well. Annotating the interface is not a must.

Comment: @Naman is your point _just_ about the annotation? if so, yes - you are correct.

Comment: Also, that `System.out.println((Today) today::getTodayDate);` seems strange enough to say `today` is calling a method of its own functional interface type. Couldn't it be just `System.out.println(today);` in that case?
Apart from that, I was actually inferring the question to be as simple as `Today today = LocalDate::now;
        System.out.println(today.getTodayDate());` to have a correct implementation.

Comment: @Naman well the OP did `System.out.println(today::getTodayDate)` initially, for this to compile a cast is needed, IFF I understood your point correctly. May be you are right about the simplicity of the question,... can't tell.

Comment: How can it be ```java.util.Supplier``` ? That has method ```get()``` not ```getTodayDate()```.

Comment: @wilmol oracle tutorial will help you here... That `getTodayDate` is an implementation of that `get`

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for the detailed explanation, I haven't used a lot of Java8 features, trying to get more familiar with it. Go through some tutorials of java8 but normally they give VERY simple example